# How to find the source of the jQuery error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-migrate

I have a page which references jQuery 3.3.1, jQuery-Migrate 1.4.1 and Bootstrap 3.3.7.  When I click anywhere on the page, I get the following error in the console:

```
jquery-3.3.1.js?v=2018.8.0.1-develop:1541 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
    at Function.Sizzle.error (jquery-3.3.1.js?v=2018.8.0.1-develop:1541)
    at Sizzle.tokenize (jquery-3.3.1.js?v=2018.8.0.1-develop:2193)
    at Sizzle.select (jquery-3.3.1.js?v=2018.8.0.1-develop:2620)
    at Function.Sizzle (jquery-3.3.1.js?v=2018.8.0.1-develop:845)
    at Function.a.find (jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js?v=2018.8.0.1-develop:2)
    at jQuery.fn.init.find (jquery-3.3.1.js?v=2018.8.0.1-develop:2873)
    at jQuery.fn.init.a.fn.find (jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js?v=2018.8.0.1-develop:2)
    at a.fn.init.jQuery.fn.init (jquery-3.3.1.js?v=2018.8.0.1-develop:2983)
    at new a.fn.init (jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js?v=2018.8.0.1-develop:2)
    at jQuery (jquery-3.3.1.js?v=2018.8.0.1-develop:139)
```

From the error `unrecognized expression: #`, it's clear to me that there is code like below, where the variable is either blank/null/undefined:

```
$('#' + someBlankVariable).method();
```

I searched for `'#' +` and placed breakpoints on all found instances and none of them are getting hit with a blank variable.

So, given that the entire error stack is in jQuery and jQuery-migrate, how can I determine what is actually causing the error?

Comment: Usually caused by incompatible versions of JQ migrate?

Comment: This looks like a missin quote (or double quote) in a jQuery selector somewhere. For that kind of stuff, I use [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/) to keyword search through code files.

Comment: Now... Now one can tell more from the error... That sadly isn't helping.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Missing quote as in `#'`?

Comment: Yes... That is my feeling... ;)

Comment: With Agent Ransack, you can search within the files of a whole directory an you can use a regex... I would search for `\(#["|']`....

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Unfortunately nothing was found.

Comment: Using AR? ok... Then search all the `#` and look them all... Open a beer and keep your smile. I'm sure it will bring you to a line you edited minutes before the crash... ;)

Comment: There is a date filter to in AR... If you want to skip old files ;)

Comment: Last advise... Be sure you trashed your browser cache. I often spent precious time looking for a "ghost bug". ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette These are all "old" files.  I upgraded from jQuery 1.7.2 to 3.3.1.  In 1.7.2 $(`#`) would basically return nothing.  In the current version, it throws the error.

Comment: I see. But I never upgraded such "old" code. Can't help on this.

Comment: It is not a missing quote. Please post a link to your page or your code so people could find the bug.

Comment: Notice that the stack trace doesn't show the function calling `jQuery()`. This suggests that it's being called from top-level code. That should narrow your search, look for `$(` and `jQuery(` at top-level in your scripts.

Comment: @KoshVery Here is the URL where this happens: https://xomeretail.stage.rsiteweb.com/homes-for-sale/7446-Latigo-Drive-Huntington-Beach-CA-92648-247764199?minifycss=false&minifyjs=false

Comment: I opened your page and didn't get an error. Do we have to do something to trigger the error?

Comment: @Barmar Click anywhere on the page.

Comment: I think it's happening somewhere in Bootstrap, but that's minified so it's hard for me to follow it from there.

Comment: You have another error with Light Gallery plugin... On fullscreen close: `lightgallery-all.1.2.19.min.js?v=2019.2.0.13-release:4 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Document not active`. -- Maybe it's related (and maybe not!)... You actually use version 1.2.19 and the [current version](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/) is 1.6.11

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette You are right - our QA didn't catch that.  It doesn't seem to affect any functionality though.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I got to the bottom of it.  Found it when QA reported that the Share link wasn't working (with the same error).  The issue was `data-target="#"` attribute in an `<a href=""` element.  Once I removed it all errors went away.  I am still confused why an attribute on a link attribute caused an error when simply clicking on a page.  Perhaps the event was bubbling up.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Man... Keep breathing. You are on a Q/A website. While having a QA peek question versus jQuery version (and migration sh%t). --- If you found an answer yourself, you can answer yourself on SO (and earn some rep points). Be as descriptive as you can ;) --- I'm sure you know that.

Answer (score 0):

It generating cause of the following attribute:

`href="#"`

Replacing it with the attribute

```
href="javascript:void(0)"
```